# Is there any working implementation of Google Docs on Honeycomb?

Tags: google-drive, 3.2-honeycomb

Simple question. I need to edit some Google documents on my EEE Pad Transformer with Honeycomb 3.2. I want few basic features.

- I want my changes to be displayed corectly in File/See revision history
- I want to be able to browse the file only with keyboard (that means up and down keys on the physical keyboard).
- I want to use my localized, non-US keyboard, which I have on Transformer and which works on most of the applications

There were few ways people told me. None of them works.

- Google Docs in mobile version looks ugly on tablet, but mainly, I am **not able to browse the file with up and down keys**. Moreover, the cursor jumps like crazy, so I often delete some text accidentaly when I want to delete something else, and there is no undo in the whole thing.
- the application "Google Docs" in the market does the same thing.
- the external applications, like Documents to Go, which are paid, do work more sanely, but still, when I upload the document, it replaces the whole revision, so I don't see any changes in revisions, just one version replacing the other.The same thing happens when I remotely connect to my server with SSH and use the python API (yeah, I tried everything).
- the desktop version of Google Docs doesn't work **at all**, I can't enter single letter, no matter how hard I try. It looks beautiful, though, which is awesome.

edit:

- what **sort of** works is opening desktop version of Google Docs in newest Firefox beta. However - for some reason, Firefox takes all keypresses as coming from US keyboard, while I have clearly selected  localized keboard (which I have).

So, is there any working implementation for Google Docs? I thought that because Android is from Google and Docs are from google, it will work seamlessly, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a recent (around 5-Oct-2011) update of the [offical Google Docs App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs), with the following changes:

## What's new in this version:

1. Optimized experience for tablet users, Honeycomb (Android 3.0+)

   - New 3-panel interface for improved browsing
   - Details panel showing a thumbnail and sharing information
   - Improved sharing experience with autocomplete system
   - Landscape or portrait mode
2. Improved video playback

---

Maybe it fixes the problems you described. I am sure Google will further work on the tablet compatibility of the Google Docs app, it's just a matter of time.

Comment: Well, it DOES improve the overview of all documents, but that frankly works in browser, too. But once I got into editing mode, I got switched back to the regular old mobile version.

And I wouldn't be so optimistic about the second thing, too. Google introduced new, better interface for Google Docs, that is completely redesigned. And guess what. It works even WORSE on Android tablets than the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

One working solution is to remotely connect to linux server through VNC and do it there. But that feels so very, very wrong.